# Intuition for the vanishing expectation of score? $E[S(\theta)] =0$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose $f$ is a probability density on $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is some parameter.

Define $$S(\theta) := \log \big( \frac{\partial f(y; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \big)$$

Then I'm trying to show that $E[S(\theta)] = 0$. The derivation shown in my class is first noticing that, when $L(\theta; y) = f(y; \theta)$ and then seeing that:

\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\partial 1}{\partial \theta}dy \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int f(y; \theta) dy \\
&= \int f(y; \theta) \frac{ \frac{ \partial L(\theta; y) }{\partial \theta} }{ L(\theta; y) } dy \\
&=\int f(y; \theta) \frac{ \partial \log(L(\theta; y)) }{ \partial \theta} dy\\
&= E[S(\theta)]
\end{align}

I think that my lack of intuition for this derivation may come from a weak background in analysis, that is, I'm not so intuitively clear on what conditions are required for interchanging differentiation and integration and so perhaps without this intuition I don't see why this result is obvious.

So, I was trying to gain more intuition by proceeding more directly, starting with $E[S(\theta)]$ and then unpacking the result until I arrived at $$E[S(\theta)] = \int \frac{ \partial f(y; \theta) }{\partial \theta } dy$$

and from here, it is not obvious to me that I should be able to interchange integration and differentiation and so I don't know how to proceed directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that the integral and derivative can be interchanged is part of the assumptions ("regularity conditions").

Comment: Sure, but why do we need this assumption?